# JQuery: How to return to the exact same scroll position when going back to previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long list of items and when I clicked into each item and return to the main list, the scroll position was lost.

How can I return to the same exact scroll position using jQuery? Is there any easy way to do it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.update-button').click(function (){
    sessionStorage.scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(sessionStorage.scrollPos);
  });
});

var init = function () {
    //get scroll position in session storage
    $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollPos || 0)
};
window.onload = init;
```

Above is what my code looks like. I tried to log the position and sessionStorage.scrollPos was 0. I am pretty sure I scrolled the page to somewhere.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is default behavior in most browsers unless you're doing something to break it.

Comment: I used a table sorter jQuery which might affected the default? How can I restore the default then? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You need to store value of scroll position in sessionStorage (or any storage) and re use it again on page load.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    //set scroll position in session storage
    sessionStorage.scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
});
var init = function () {
    //get scroll position in session storage
    $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollPos || 0)
};
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question...how can I use the functions you wrote...? I am pretty new to jQuery :( Should I place your code in document.ready wrapper?

Comment: There are 2 events used in my code.1st is scroll event which you can place anywhere which will store the current scroll positions. 2nd is `window.onload` event which will be called once all the content in the webpage is loaded. You can keep it at the same level where your `ready` event is written, not inside it..

Comment: Thanks! One more question...Can you see my post for updates...I cannot edit it here.

Comment: sessionStorage.scrollPos returned  0 when I tried to log the result. Do you know why...? Thanks!

Comment: you may try '$("body").on("scroll", function(){ sessionstorage.......})'

Answer (score 3):

Just modifying @Rayon Answer if it doesn't work someone.

```
$("body").on("scroll", function () {
    //set scroll position in session storage
    sessionStorage.scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
});
var init = function () {
    //get scroll position in session storage
    $("body").scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollPos || 0)
};
window.onload = init;
```

You can replace the `$("body")` with the top most element in your HTML. I am using framework7 mobile applicaiton and I need to use `$(".page-content")`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

No easy solution, but on the click event where the redirect takes place, get the current scroll position using

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Then store the value of the scroll variable into the localstorage (cookies if localstorage is not available).

Then on page load look for the scroll position from local storage if available and if so move to that position.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to wrap your code inside the click function and log it. The scroll was 0. Do you know what might happened?

Comment: I don't know , but scrollTop() works. You can just try it here in stackoverflow. Open the console in Edge or chrome dev tools and try this code you will see it will print different numbers based on the scroll position.

Comment: Could you post your code so that I can check it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried to use $(window).scrollTop() on stackoverflow and this function works fine. However, when I use it on my website, it stopped functioning...do you have any idea why? Thank you!

Comment: My website has a sidebar. Could it be the reason?

Comment: Yes if your website has a sidebar then instead of $(window) you need to find the div element for which the side bar is being displayed and then use $("#div_id") where div_id is the id of the div for which a scroll bar is being displayed.

Comment: Thanks! I had it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

this work for readmore article or hide article, for get current position height of readmore clicked.

#note: you need toggle button readmore and hide

```
let readhide = document.querySelectorAll('.read-hide');
let readmore = document.querySelectorAll('.read-more');
readmore.forEach((more,key) => {
    let height, moreHeight;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event){
        height = Math.floor(event.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop);
    });
    
    more.addEventListener('click', function(){
        moreHeight = height;
    });
    
    readhide[key].addEventListener('click', function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, moreHeight);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a href="javascript:window.history.back()">Return Text </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This.

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>


function goBack() {
  window.history.go(-1);
}
```