# window.history.go(-1) + targeted location

Tags: javascript, browser-history, history.js

How can I be more specific than `window.history.go(-1)`. Going back to the previous page is one thing but I would like to go back precisely where I left that page.

The action is: I'm looking at images, I click on one of them which takes me somewhere else and when I click `window.history.go(-1)` I'm back precisely where I left instead of being back at the top of the page.

Comment: What’s the context? Do you have control over where they came from?

Comment: I'm developing the site via Webflow as my client wants it there—don't know if you're familiar with it. I would normally be able to create IDs for my elements, which would make it really easy to track down but in this case I can't. That's why I was wondering if I could find a general solution applicable to any images from the page I've clicked on.

Comment: So you just scroll your page, not actually reload/navigate from one page to another?

Comment: I do navigate from one page to another. I'm scroll on one page and click on an image which takes me to another page where I have a button (window.history.go(-1)) but I can't add specific IDs to the elements on my previous page so I can't have specific locations.

Comment: I'm wondering if I can found/create a general rule on top of window.history.go(-1) which would allow me to come back to the location where I've click on the page. Not just at the top of that page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the page that you're coming from (For example you're able to add some javascript) then you could take a look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32573714/7535148).

However without somehow storing the position before leaving the page I don't think there is anyway to do it (There's no window.history.go(-1).lastScroll method for example)

Comment: Cheers, this might be a solution. The page where I want to go back to is to be understood as a static page so it gives me more freedom inside the Webflow framework.