# Click on <details> (not <summary>) to close "disclosure statement"?

Tags: html, toggle

Following the simple example shown here, [<details>: The Details disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) [Mozilla.org], how can I click in the "details" to collapse those details?

For example, in the animated GIF below the upper portion is the "summary", which when clicked toggles the "details" (below).

In some instances those details will be quite long; I want to be able to click there, to collapse those details (rather than scrolling back up to the "summary" portion).

I am generating my HTML page via Ajax, so an Ajax/JQuery solution is likely what I'm after.

Here is the relevant section.

```js
(function ($) {
    if (snippets_arr.length > 2) {
        fq_snippet += '<details><summary>' + snippets_arr.slice(0,2).join('<br/>');

        fq_snippet += '<br/>[toggle]</summary>' + snippets_arr.slice(2,).join('<br/>') + '</details>';
    }
    else {
        fq_snippet += snippets_arr.join('<br/>');
    }

  // Addendum: the solution involved this part of that file:
  init: function () {
      // add code here ...
        });
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

[image: HTML element]

---

**Update 1:** solved, after chat with, code from @a.mola. Clicking on "summary" (top portion) toggles open / closed the "details" view (bottom portion).

New functionality: clicking on the "details" (when open, of course) collapses the "details" view.

This applies to all (i.e. multiple) "details/summary" elements on a page.

[image]

---

**Update 2**

I modified the code to remember and return to the scroll position, after you collapse the  section.

```js
var scrollPosition = null;

/* REMEMBER, SET SCROLL POSITION
  *
  * Here I implemented a scroll position ["scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop(); ..."] addition
  * to my "<details>" code, so that when you collapse a long <details> section you return to the 
  * original <summary> position.
  *
  *   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441065/how-to-detect-scroll-position-of-page-using-jquery
  *   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836428/how-to-maintain-page-scroll-position-after-a-jquery-event-is-carried-out/10836745
  *   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573532/jquery-how-to-return-to-the-exact-same-scroll-position-when-going-back-to-previ
  */

$(document).click(function(event) {
    /* ORIGINALLY (per StackOverflow discussion with user a.mola -- referenced above):
      *
      *   if (event.target.tagName == 'DETAILS' && event.target.hasAttribute('open')) event.target.removeAttribute('open');
      *
      * Modified to following, to allow use of "scrollPosition" to reset scroll position
      * when collapsing long <details> sections.
      */

    // if (event.target.tagName == 'DETAILS' && event.target.hasAttribute('closed')) {
    if (event.target.tagName == 'SUMMARY') {
        // SAVE THE CURRENT SCROLL POSITION:
        scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        // console.log('[summary click] scrollPosition', scrollPosition, '| type:', typeof scrollPosition)
        // ----------------------------------------
        /* NOTE: "return" here exits this AND following if statement: */
        // return scrollPosition;
    }   /* if (event.target.tagName == 'SUMMARY') {} */

    if (event.target.tagName == 'DETAILS' && event.target.hasAttribute('open')) {
        scrollPosition = scrollPosition;
        // ----------------------------------------
        /* COLLAPSE <details> ELEMENT BY CLICKING ON THAT [<details>] ELEMENT:
          *   Per user a.mola:
          *   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66609261/click-on-details-not-summary-to-close-disclosure-statement/66609543#66609543
          */
        event.target.removeAttribute('open');
        // ----------------------------------------
        // SET THE SCROLL POSITION FROM STORED SESSION VALUE:
        $(window).scrollTop(scrollPosition);
    }  /* if (event.target.tagName == 'DETAILS' && event.target.hasAttribute('open')) {} */
});    /* $(document).click(function(event) {} */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever the `<summary></summary>` tag is clicked / touched the open attribute is set on the `<details></details>` tag to expose the extra content.

By simply toggling the attribute on the `<details></details>` tag would implement the functionality you need.

```js
(function($) {
    // ...
    $(document).click(function(event) {
        if (event.target.tagName == 'DETAILS' && event.target.hasAttribute('open')) event.target.removeAttribute('open');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details>
  <summary>Details</summary>
  Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
```

Comment: Hi; thank you for the response. I saw several similar solutions (StackOverflow ...), but I could not get them to work.  I thought it was because I am generating that decisions/summary in an Ajax-generated HTML page; however, even when I made a simple HTML page (I'll append that code to my question, above) using your code, it did not work in either Firefox 86 or Opera 74. This JSFiddle DOES work (with your code), however. https://jsfiddle.net/10t26hmq/  ... it is exactly what I want.

Comment: Well then, is it all okay now? If yes please can you mark the answer correct?

Comment: No, not yet; sorry for the confusion - see my comments: the JSFiddle and the simple HTML example work; my Ajax code is not working.

Comment: The code you're using to generate this page from, do you know how to get exactly what you in the details tag? Can I see the code generating the HTML?

Comment: @VictoriaStuart Yes ma, I've edited my code now... Unless you want to do something else to the `summary` tag there's no need to select it

Comment: Hey, that's awesome, @a.mola!  Very close.  The issue is I have multiple details/summary elements, so that code is getting confused.  I'll append another animated GIF to illustrate. :-D

Comment: I've fixed that issue as well, this time when the `document` is clicked it checks if the element it clicked has the `open` attribute and if its tag is the `details` element. Try the code now ma @VictoriaStuart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229847/discussion-between-victoria-stuart-and-a-mola).

Comment: There is a bug and code snippet gives an error. On modern FireFox at least.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix. When I wrote the code, I just started using SO and I just used the snippet to format my code. So the `snippets_arr` variable was undefined here. But worked for her when she needed it. I've fixed it now. You can test it out

Comment: @a.mola Works fine now. Up-voted. I'm struggling with a similar problem that you might be able to fix? [html <details> when <summary> expanded requires scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482194/html-details-when-summary-expanded-requires-scrolling)

Answer (score 1):

I think slightly better than a.mola answer would be to select only "details" element and not test every element for clicking....

```js
(function($) {
    // ...
    $('details').click(function(event) {
        if (event.target.hasAttribute('open')) event.target.removeAttribute('open');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details>
  <summary>Details</summary>
  Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
<p>other tags are not test for clicking</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Btw I found kind of hack solution to do it totally without javaScript :)

Another advantage in this hack is that you can also modify summary text for open/close cases. I use it for remove text "click for details"

Basically you put all text into `summary` tag.

Then add one class for text that shall be visible for closed details

and another class for text that shall be visible for opened details.

Then with CSS use selector `details[open]` and `details:not([open])` along with your open/close class and use `display:none`.

```css
details[open] > summary .summaryOpen {
    color: green;
}
/* when summary is open hide text with our class .summaryClose */
details[open] > summary .summaryClose {
    display:none;
}
/* when summary is closed hide text with our class .summaryOpen */
details:not([open]) > summary .summaryOpen{
    display:none;
}

details:not([open]) > summary .summaryClose {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    <span class="summaryClose">Summary ...(click for details)...</span>
    <span class="summaryOpen">Summary text text text</span>
    <p class="summaryOpen">details which are also in summary section... but not visible for closed details...</p>
  </summary>
</details>
```